# Why we have to reshape the array values when we are going to predict results using the predict() method of linear regression

Tags: machine-learning

While we are predicting it is mandatory to give the input to predict() as the 2-D array. why it is necessary ?

Comment: What  library, algorithm and input are you using?

Comment: i am using numpy for  EDA and sklearn for modeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

predict requires the argument as 2-D array because it transforms the rows and columns in the features and observation vecotr